# is it a good practice (maybe some known design pattern?) to tell subclasses to do something to the superclass's protected variables?

Tags: c++

Is this a good pattern?

```
BaseClass {
protected:
  Data m_data;
public:
  Interesting public_method() {
    //returns something interesting about m_data
    //what exactly depends on what the subclass put into m_data
  }
}

DerivedClass {
public:
  DerivedClass() { //properly populate m_data }
}
```

The drawback with this is that things are too "loose" and not compile-time enforced because the subclass programmer is only told to do something, not really forced to do it, so I wonder whether this is considered good practice by seasoned c++ coders.

Any good way out or better ways?

If only the superclass constructor could be forced to be called AFTER the subclass constructor did its work. Then the superclass constructor could have the required parameters in it

c++ does not allow this :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If only the superclass constructor could be forced to be called AFTER the subclass constructor did its work. Then the superclass constructor could have the required parameters in it.

The *ctor-initializer-list* is quite powerful.  Although you can only use expressions, those expressions can include function calls.  Virtually anything you can do inside the constructor body can be achieved from inside the initializer list.

Of course, you must respect construction order, so you can't call member functions on the base class before initializing it.  But you can access the base class when initializing members.

```
class BaseClass
{
  Data m_data;
protected:
  BaseClass( Data&& data ) m_data(data) {}
public:
  Interesting public_method() {
    //returns something interesting about m_data
    //what exactly depends on what the subclass put into m_data
  }
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
  static Data make_arg_into_data( const T& arg ) { /* calculate and return the right value for m_data */ }
  static Interesting make_arg_into_member_init( BaseClass* pThis, const T& arg ) { return pThis->public_method(); }
  V m_member;
public:
  DerivedClass( T arg ) BaseClass(make_arg_into_data(arg)), m_member(make_arg_into_member_init(this, arg)) {  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a pattern, this is an anti pattern. Rule of thumb: protected variables are bad. Inherited behavior (inheriting from concrete classes in general) is bad. Of course there might be times when there's a reason to ignore either of these, but without you saying what you are actually trying to do it's hard to tell.

Comment: You're painting with a very broad brush by discouraging inheritance of non-pure classes.  IMO you've badly overgeneralized advice you didn't fully understand.

Comment: @BenVoigt Inheriting behavior can quickly lead to tight coupling. I explicitly said that it's not some ironclad rule, just that you should know why you're breaking it if you do. A decent enough counterexample would be Qt - while it's technically still not necessary there, the inheritance doesn't generally get in your way.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, a protected variable should never be used. I prefer to use a private variable, with a protected method. In this way, if you want to use a polymorfic object you can override your method and avoid "bad surprises". If your class is `final`, of course you can use directly the protected var.

Comment: There is no final keyword in c++

Comment: @Jay: In C++03, virtual inheritance from a class with private constructor and friendship accomplishes that.  In C++11, there is in fact a `final` keyword.  `class DerivedClass final : public BaseClass {};`

Comment: Yes, but the question is tagged C++ not C++03.

Answer (score 1):

To me, this doesn't sound quite right. Although it's not unheard of to have the derived class make calls to the baseclass, it is more commonly that the derived class will override the (virtual) `public_method` to provide that information.

Or, as suggested, use a factory function. Or a static "constructor" member function, so rather than calling new, you call a function that calls `new` and the `special function to make set the data`.

All possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use a factory:

```
BaseClass {
private:
  Data m_data;
public:
  void setData(const Data& data) { m_data = data; }
  virtual Data generateData() = 0;
};

struct Factory
{
   template<class T>
   static BaseClass* getInstance()
   {
       BaseClass* t = new T;
       t->setData(t->generateData());
       return t;
   }
};
```

and call it as

```
BaseClass* p = Factory::getInstance<Derived>();
```

As you can see, non-abstract derived classes are forced to call `generateData`, so they will have to generate a valid `Data`.

I only used raw pointers for ease of writing this, don't :)

Comment: s/populateData/generateData/ ??